# Mouse Event handling group of circles (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, java-8

I want to change radius when i click on a circle.
All circles in the groupe "circles".

How i can set the "circle1" Radius in a for each while?

```
        for (Node circle1: circles.getChildren()) {
            if (circle1.getTranslateX() != circle.getTranslateX()) {

                circle.setRadius(60);
                //circle1.setRadius(40); <- FAIL

            }
```

full code

```
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.web("#2E3436"));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    Group circles = new Group();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(40, Color.web("#2E3436", 0.05));
        circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.web("#0086FF", 0.14));
        circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
        circle.setTranslateX(random() * 800);
        circle.setTranslateY(random() * 600);
        circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED , (Event event) -> {
            for (Node circle1: circles.getChildren()) {
                if (circle1.getTranslateX() != circle.getTranslateX()) {

                    circle.setRadius(60);
                    //circle1.setRadius(40);

                }
            }
        });
        circles.getChildren().add(circle);
    }   
    root.getChildren().add(circles);
    circles.setEffect(new BoxBlur(2, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast your circle1 to be a Circle and not just a Node.

Comment: How i can cast the circle1 to a Circle? `for (Circle circle1: circles.getChildren()) {` doesnt work.

Comment: ((Circle)circle1).setRadius(40);